# Accessing function from class

Tags: swift

I've just started coding and I have a problem with accessing a function from a class. I want to print the area of a triangle but it prints just " ()". Here is my code:

```
    class Shape {
    var area:Double?
    func calculateArea(valA:Double, valB: Double) {
        area = valA * valB
    }
}
class Triangle: Shape {
    override func calculateArea(valA: Double, valB: Double) {
        area = ((valA*valB)/2)
    }
}

var area1 = Triangle ()
print (area1.calculateArea(valA: 2, valB: 1))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't return nothing, so your doing an empty print.

You can print `area` value from class property:

```
area1.calculateArea(valA: 2, valB: 1)
print(area1.area)
```

or edit your functions

```
func calculateArea(valA:Double, valB: Double) -> Double {
    area = valA * valB
    return area
}
```

and

```
override func calculateArea(valA: Double, valB: Double) -> Double {
    area = ((valA*valB)/2)
    return area
}
```

then you can print directly the function result

```
print(area1.calculateArea(valA: 2, valB: 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `calculateArea` function does not return anything, so there is nothing to print.

You have to call the function and then print the `area` property on your `area1` object:

```
var area1 = Triangle()
area1.calculateArea(valA: 2, valB: 1)
print(area1.area)
```